# Integral on surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Please help me calculate integral on surface.

$$\iint\!(2-y)\,dS $$
$$ 0\leq z\leq 1;\,  y =1 $$
I can't understand what should I do with '$z$' coordinate. I assume I should do something with it, not to leave blank.
Maybe like this?
$$= \iint\!dy dz  = 1?$$

Comment: Hint: with the integral of a single variable--that is, $y=f(x)$, do you do anything with the $y$, or just "leave it blank"?

Comment: What is the integral of the function within a constant $y$?  That is: What is the integral of that function from $y = 1$ to $y = 1$?

Comment: I have only this input data. So I think $$=\int\int (2-1)*\sqrt(1+d(y)^2) ..=  $$ don't know what to do with z-coordinate 
I get this integral from my home-work.
@ZettaSuro , I replaced y with it value.

Comment: Another question. $2-y$ doesn't tell us anything about the surface. Is the surface $x=2-y$ or $z=2-y$? I'm assuming it's $x=2-y$ but I just want to be sure.

Comment: So I see you facing the same problem as me. As for me, I found that maybe the surface is a line? But can't figure out how to use z-coordinate in this equation. Maybe you can suggest me a best solution for this problem so I can write in my work?

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what your surface is.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an example from a book...

Comment: Here is the [method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393386/how-to-solve-this-integral-for-a-hyperbolic-bowl). By the way, consider up voting the answer if benfit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely there is part of a surface $S$ which is bounded between $0\leq z\leq 1$ and $y=1$.

If the integral is on the surface $y=1$ and bounded between $0\leq z\leq 1$, then this surface is an infinite strip parallel to the $x$-axis, there is no way the integral is $1$ unless you have a bound on $x$ as well.

If it is the former case, what you wanna do is to look for a parametrization of $S$:
$$
S: \mathbf{\Phi}(u,v) = \big(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)\big),
$$
for $u\in [a,b]$, $v\in [c,d]$, then
$$
\iint_S (2-y)\,dS = \int^d_c\int^b_a \big(2-y(u,v)\big)\,\left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}}{\partial v}\right|\,dudv.
$$

---

EDIT: for the $z = 1$ case, you certain have:
$$
\iint_S (2-z)\,dS = \int^{1}_0\color{red}{\int^{b}_{a}} (2-z)\sqrt{1 + (z_x)^2 + (z_y)^2} \,\color{red}{dx} dy  = \color{red}{\int^{b}_{a}dx}\int^{1}_0(2-1)dy.
$$
Like I said in the original answer, you have to have a bound on $x$, otherwise the surface is infinite.

Comment: As my teacher says for the another example, I think maybe in example below we can do the same
$$z=1, ds = \sqrt{(1+(z'_x)^{2}+(z'_y)^{2}} =1 $$,
So The answer will be $$ \int_0^1 (2-1) dy = 1$$

Comment: @wsevendays Please see my edit.

Comment: yes, you are right, I've missed x coordinate. So I think this example is incorrectly writed.